# spark mapwithstate how to access all keys built over multiple microbatches

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to access the state of all keys that has been built by several microbatches.

```
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(stateUpdate _)
  .numPartitions(numPartitions)
  .timeout(Seconds(7200))
  // ... multiple steps....
  val sessionizedTuples =  endTimedTuples.mapWithState(stateSpec)
  // ..... multiple steps.....
```

I am successfully updating state of keys by micro batch and eventually end up with lot of keys. What is the way to get all the keys and their state so i can apply some rdd function on them, all the methods i see is at micro batch level and not on the whole set build over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```scala
val state = sessionizedTuples.stateSnapshots()
```

`stateSnapshots` : Return a pair DStream where each RDD is the snapshot of the state of all the keys.

Comment: I initially thought this was returning only the microbatch's state, but looks like it does return all old keys since inception too. Thanks